# Is there a way to forbid multi-tasking in iOS 4?

Tags: iphone, multitasking

I want my app to quit when the user taps the home button, without going to the background. Is this possible?

Comment: Application does not run in background, set .app plist .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222463/i-dony-want-my-app-to-run-in-background-on-iphone/3222489#3222489

Answer (score 6):

Set the key `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` to `true` in your `info.plist`. See the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html).