# How to stop your app appearing at the app running area, when you have explicitly stop running the app in backgroun

Tags: ios4, multitasking

Basically i was looking for the way to stop the application form running at the background and the following question helped me.

[How to prevent my app from running in the background on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222463/how-to-prevent-my-app-from-running-in-the-background-on-the-iphone)

But when i used this method, my app starts from beginning but when i double tap the home page, it still shows my app there.. Is it how iOS 4 work or i am missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that it correct. All the apps are shown there and the ones that don't support background mode will simply be relaunched.