# programmatically prevent app from running in background iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an app that will run in the background but there is one case where I do not want that to happen, can I achieve this programmatically?

I know I can opt out by [changing this plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222463/how-to-prevent-my-app-from-running-in-the-background-on-the-iphone) value but what about at run time?

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish? Why do you think that preventing the app from suspending is necessary to achieve this?

Comment: I second what @Jonah says... why would it hurt to let it run?

Comment: I am totally deleting my Core Data datastore and I want them to start the app fresh, this is an easy way to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use exit(0) b/c apple does not allow you to close the app without user knowing it.

From Technical Q&A QA1561 [How do I programmatically quit my iPhone application?](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1561/_index.html).

> There is no API provided for gracefully terminating an iPhone
>   application. Under the iPhone OS, the
>   user presses the Home button to close
>   applications. Should your application
>   have conditions in which it cannot
>   provide its intended function, the
>   recommended approach is to display an
>   alert for the user that indicates the
>   nature of the problem and possible
>   actions the user could take - turning
>   on WiFi, enabling Location Services,
>   etc. Allow the user to terminate the
>   application at their own discretion.

Comment: Right, but it is still okay to call exit when the app is running in the background. the user won't notice. There are many apps that do this. See my answer.

Comment: Note that the QA is somewhat outdated: "**Last updated: 2008-08-27**" - thats before Multitasking was introduced with iOS4 !

Answer (score 7):

Add the variable UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend (Application does not run in background) to your applications plist and assign the value YES.

Comment: OP explicitly asks how to do this "at run time"

Comment: Thank you man its work, for several months I am looking for this solution

Answer (score 6):

You can close the app by calling `exit(0)` in `applicationDidEnterBackground`.

Answer (score -3):

Calling exit() is discouraged, and not informing the user that the app is going to terminate is also discouraged.  So you need to get the OS to kill your app (as it normally would do over a long enough period of operation) while simultaneously informing the user.  One way of doing this, while using only legal APIs, is to dirty absolutely as many memory pages as possible (malloc and bzero), then call Safari with a URL to a hoggish website explaining why the app is going to quit.  Safari will require enough memory to display the website that your app will be terminated by the OS, just as the user is being properly informed.

Sleeping until the OS kill timer kills your app will also kill your app, but this non-responsive delay will lock up the UI, which isn't a good user experience.

Comment: -1 Im sorry, but that seems like a terrible idea. What happens when a new iPhone comes out with more ram or mobile safari gets more efficient? Calling exit() may be discouraged. But freezing your application and/or removing control of the device from the user, in the attempt to close your application, is outright shameful.

Comment: @RTS - Unforetunately, shameful things happen far too often, such as when an app detects that it has been somehow modified.

Comment: -1. The reason Apple doesn't want you to programmatically exit is that it makes for bad usability to do so. But this is far worse! It's not guaranteed to work (because you don't know the device's memory size), if it works it will also kill all other background apps (because you drain the memory), and it would feel really, really wierd to have an application open a web page to tell me it's closing.