# Application crash right after DidBecomeActive

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I am getting a few errors from my program when it resigns active, then when it is opened again, it crashes.

(Most times when the app is opened, it opens on the same view it was left in before, but in some cases this is not convenient.
I would like, each time the app is opened, for it to launch in a completely new instance.

Is there any way to make this possible, and to terminate all programs running when the app is closed?)

**Edit**
Ok, I understand it is quite difficult to terminate the program under the rules.

What I have, is when the game is being played, if you click home, then go back onto the game, the app will crash with "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".
I think this might have something to do with some of the arrays that are running, but I have been debugging for a long time and I can't get anything to work.

It crashes right after: `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {`

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're on OS X, then I pretty sure you can do something like [NSApp terminate] or something like that

Comment: I suggest you find and fix the source of the crash instead of terminating the app. I suspect there will be other issues that will show up unexpectedly if you don't address the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's arguably a bit of a sledgehammer approach, but you could call `exit(0);` in your application delegate's implementation of `-applicationWillResignActive:` That should ensure that every time your app is opened, it's starting from scratch.

Comment: Would work for development, but Apple will not allow an app doing this on the store.

Comment: What specific rule does this violate? (Not disagreeing, just curious)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6637693/201863

Comment: The comments on that answer seem to indicate that calling `exit()` is quite common.