# Simulating iOS opening an app fresh in the background

Tags: ios, objective-c, testing

I have a crash in an iOS app that I believe it triggered from iOS opening the app in the background. I'd like to be able to test this hypothesis, but am not sure if I can trigger iOS to open a closed app in the background for testing purposes.

I am specifically looking to have iOS open this app fresh - i.e. not when the app is still active and placed in the background, but when the app is fully closed and iOS triggers a re-open.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why not just Force quit?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean a bit? And will doing so trigger the operating system to restart the application?

Comment: If you want to open an app fresh, force quit the previously opened app. Double click the home button and swipe the app to the tap. And open the app !!!

Comment: I'm asking how to simulate the operating system opening the app in the background - not how I can open the app myself

Comment: Did you look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637559/programmatically-prevent-app-from-running-in-background-ios? IT might be helpful to you.