# Killing iOS app upon user request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, user-controls

So here is the issue I am facing. Certain portions of the application I am building open some c network sockets that allow connections to various servers/services. However, if the application goes to sleep, these socket connections are lost, and error out when trying to reload them. So what I want to do is basically notify the user when the app launches again, that the application needs to be restarted. The main question is, can I present them with a button that will kill the app by using exit(0) without my app getting rejected?

Apple says that the user should be in control of when the app is killed, and in this case I see that they are, but I am not sure of Apple's opinion on this. Has anyone else used this? Have you been rejected for this? Thanks in advance for any advice!

**EDIT:**

Thank you everyone for your advice. I am trying to take everything into consideration, but because the app needs to be submitted ASAP, I just need to know, if we can not get another solution, if the above proposed solution, will get rejected or not.

Comment: Have you tried not allowing the app to run in the background? Then it will be killed whenever the user exits to the home screen. This might be a bit aggressive, but would solve the problem.

Comment: How do I allow it to run in the background? Is this something simple, and does apple actually allow this without getting rejected?

Comment: I think you should see the fact that it *needs* to be restarted as a bug. You really should be able to cope with the app going to the background and back again.

Comment: It's simple... change the plist. I've added an answer below to avoid prolonged comments.

Comment: I see the comment, the problem is, I only need this to happen for one section of the application. So universally just killing the app, is a bad idea and that will look like a crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is pretty explicit about this, "There is no API provided for gracefully terminating an iOS application." See [Technical Q&A QA1561
How do I programmatically quit my iOS application?](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1561/).

To be blunt, terminating an app to cleanup a socket is just like dealing with memory management by forcing an app to exit instead of calling `release`.

Comment: -1 : There is a public pair of APIs for graceful termination of an app, and plenty of apps do it.  Build the app with the UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend plist key, plus have the app send a legal and useful URL to Safari.  Your app will be terminated.

Comment: I know that it is not a graceful method at all, it is a time constraint issue. Do not think I am happy that I have to kill the application to clean this up.

Answer (score 4):

Your application delegate receives notifications when significant events affect the life of the application. Rather than ask your user to recreate a session, you should attempt to discontinue network operations and then resume them at the appropriate times in the application's lifecycle automatically.

You can gracefully kill network sockets (amongst other things) in any number of places as the application prepares to exit or enter the background via callbacks in your application delegate:

```
applicationWillResignActive:
applicationWillEnterBackground:
applicationWillTerminate:
```

Potentially reconstruct sockets in:

```
applicationDidBecomeActive
applicationWillEnterForeground
```

Comment: Already tried that and for some reason these sockets do not want to get reconstructed properly. We think the problem is that when the app goes to sleep, they are actually losing connection to the wifi network because when you sleep your phone switches back to 3G. And when the app resumes, as with applicationDidBecomeActive, at the instant the phone becomes active again, it does not have a complete connection to that wifi network when we call that restart

Comment: So you are saying that you're unable to tear down a network session without your application being forcibly restarted? I think a better solution than to force the user to restart would be to try and figure out a away to enable and disable your network services as you need.

Comment: We are trying to do that, but are having some problems, and because we need this app soon, there is a time constraint to really get this working. So our fail safe is just killing the app with the user's approval. I just want to know if Apple will allow this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Apple will reject any app that quits itself.

Comment: No they won't.  Apple guidelines are clear about that. Apple recommends not to do so as user can interpret this as a crash and might gave you a bad comment on the AppleStore.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried not allowing the app to run in the background? Then it will be killed whenever the user exits to the home screen. This might be a bit aggressive, but would solve the problem. From Apple's opting out of background execution:

> "If you do not want your application to remain in the background when
>   it is quit, you can explicitly opt out of the background execution
>   model by adding the UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend key to your
>   application’s Info.plist file and setting its value to YES.
>
> When an application opts out, it cycles between the not running,
>   inactive, and active states and never enters the background or
>   suspended states.
>
> When the user taps the Home button to quit the application, the
>   applicationWillTerminate: method of the application delegate is called
>   and the application has approximately five seconds to clean up and
>   exit before it is terminated and moved back to the not running state."

See also: [How to prevent my app from running in the background on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222463/how-to-prevent-my-app-from-running-in-the-background-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

What about bringing up a modal view controller telling the user to quit the application? You could make this view controller without any dismiss button, so the user is obligated to kill the app.

Comment: that is what I am doing right now, I just do not know if this will get the app rejected or not. Because this may look like a crash, but they are pushing a darn button that say "Kill App". I think it is obvious but am unsure about Apple's perspective

Comment: No, it won't be rejected. AppleGuidelines do not prevent from killing the App programmatically. I'm doing it on one of my apps that is on the AppStore.