# Debug app after device restart

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I have an issue on my iOS app that occurs every time I restart my iOS device (i.e. after turning it off and on again). I turn off the device with the app in foreground, restart it and then relaunch the app from the background.

Obviously, the Xcode console doesn't show debug message when the device is turned off and I don't manage to know what happens to the app when the device is restarted. If I restart the app from Xcode, the issue disappears and everything works flawlessly again.

Also, it seems that the app is relaunching itself from the background when the device restarts. Is it possible to prevent this behaviour and force the app to restart from scratch when I tap on the app icon or on its screen from the multitasking?

Thanks.

Comment: If your app doesn't need to run in background, you may want do do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222463/how-to-prevent-my-app-from-running-in-the-background-on-the-iphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to force close apps, double tap the home button and then you can swipe away the background process.

To debug the process after restarting the device and opening the app again, you should be able to attach the Xcode debug console to the running process. In Xcode do:

`Debug > Attach to process > [select your process]`

Comment: Yes, but this has to be done by the user. I wonder if I could detect when the device is turning off and just close the app programmatically.

Comment: If you always want to stop the app from running in the background, use the `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` key as documented here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html

If you only want to do this when the user turns off/restarts their device, then I don't think that is possible. Apple doesn't like to allow you to know what the user is up to outside of your application.

Comment: My app should run in background. How am I supposed to attach the debug to another process? Could I use another device in order to achieve that (i.e. run my app from iPhone and debug it from iPad)?

Comment: Attach your device to your mac via cable > Open your already installed app > Open Xcode > Click `Debug` in the tool bar at the top > Click `Attach to process` and select your app.

I don't think you can debug from another iOS device. Not that I know of anyway.